# using \reflectbox for a tikz symbol in addtocontents

Tags: table-of-contents, tikzsymbols

I have created a book using the latest MacTex version and typesetting with Lualatex. (`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}`)
I have tested `\reflectbox` throughout the doc and always works fine, however, when I want to use the command to flip a symbol I am including in the ToC via

```
\addtocontents{toc}{~\noindent\hfil\reflectbox{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}} \hspace{2pt} {\textbf{\large{Recipes}}} \hspace{2pt} {\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}\hfil\par}
```

I get Tex:661:Undefined Control Sequence.

I have also tried including further brackets, e.g.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{~\noindent\hfil{\reflectbox{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}} \hspace{2pt} {\textbf{\large{Recipes}}} \hspace{2pt} {\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}\hfil\par}
```

but wind up with the identical error.

Without the `\reflectbox`, the code works fine:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{~\noindent\hfil{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}} \hspace{2pt} {\textbf{\large{Recipes}}} \hspace{2pt} {\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}\hfil\par}
```

Any ideas?
James

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\usepackage[no-math]{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\setsansjfont{Hiragino Sans}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}

\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-1, -2, +3, -4, -5, +6, +7, +8}}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{japanese}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{18pt}

\usepackage [top=1.8cm,
        bottom=1.8cm,
        left=3cm,
        right=2cm,
        headheight=17pt,
        includehead,includefoot,
        %heightrounded,
        %showframe
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{18pt}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\floatsep}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{aboveskip=7pt, belowskip=-            \baselineskip,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{parsep=4pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=5pt}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array,tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb, pifont, marvosym, tikzsymbols, fdsymbol, wasysym, fontawesome, ifsym, academicons}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{orcid}{HTML}{a7cc46}
    \definecolor{RG}{HTML}{21cbbb}
    \definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1078b3}
    \definecolor{twitter}{HTML}{2aa3ef}
    \definecolor{face}{HTML}{4469b0}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\makeindex[columns=2, columnseprule, title=Index]
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[breaklinks,hidelinks,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
            colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor = blue
            }

\setlistdepth{4}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\textit{\alph*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\textit{\roman*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=$$}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %definition of the no. of levels in the ToC list

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\scriptsize{\roman{footnote}}} %fontsize footnote
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents \label{TaoCo}}} %Title of ToC

%definition of \quote margins 
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
   \list{}{%
     \leftmargin20pt   % this is the adjusting screw
     \rightmargin\leftmargin
   }
   \item\relax
}
{\endlist}
%--------------------------PAGESTYLE Preface-----------------------------------------
\fancypagestyle{preface}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\small Preface}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small Name}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\small Name}
    %\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\small \thepage}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do not post such fragments only, but the document that has this issue. As a guess: `\usepackage{graphicx}` is missing

Comment: No, don't post it as a comment. Edit your question and add the minimal  document that has this issue

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need a few `\protect` somewhere. How's `\fryingpan` defined?

Comment: @egreg: `\fryingpan` is a macro from `tikzsymbols`

Comment: I am sure my doc is highly cluttered (just started using LaTeX)... @egreg/@Christian, where would I place the \protect command? It's awkward providing a MWE as my doc has 190 pages and all is rather interlinked.

Comment: @James: Sorry, but your preamble is a mess. Most likely, it is about `\protect\reflectbox` in your `\addtocontents` calls

Comment: To provide a minimal work example you need to give the smallest amount of code possible that compiles and demonstrates your problem. Trust me, with as true MWE you won't need most of your preamble and you can omit probably all 190 pages of your real document.

Comment: Can you guys recommend a reference for me to better understand how to code a cleaner doc/check, i.e. how it could be rendered 'leaner'? E.g. for the preamble, I assume that quite a few packages are redundant as they might be called by others...

Comment: I think that your preamble is fine: you have various packages that you need to load and that's mostly what you have, together some settings using some of the packages. You can't really do much better than than.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my preamble, Andrew. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to be using this reflected frying pan a lot I suggest writing a macro for it:

```
\newcommand\napgniyrf{\protect\reflectbox{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}}
```

Note the `\protect` as suggested above in the comments. With this change your MWE (or at least what your MWE should have been! :) works fine to produce:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\napgniyrf{\protect\reflectbox{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}}
\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\noindent\hfil{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}\hspace{2pt}{\textbf{\large{Recipes}}}\hspace{2pt}{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}\hfil\par}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\noindent\hfil\napgniyrf\hspace{2pt}{\textbf{\large{Recipes}}}\hspace{2pt}{\napgniyrf}\hfil\par}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

You might also want to define

```
\newcommand\Fryingpan{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}{\fryingpan}}
```

so that you don't need to use `\fontsize` whenever you want to use a `\fryingpan`.

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `\addtocontents` is moving, so fragile commands such as `\reflectbox` should be protected. It's easier to define a robust command instead.

I'd avoid `\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}` for this: `\scalebox` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mnapgniyrf{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\fryingpan}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mfryingpan{\scalebox{2}{\fryingpan}}

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \noindent\hfil\mfryingpan
  \hspace{2pt}\textbf{\large{Recipes}}\hspace{2pt}%
  \mnapgniyrf\par
}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy, if you need to use the symbols at different sizes, is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\mnapgniyrf[1]{\scalebox{-#1}[#1]{\fryingpan}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mfryingpan[1]{\scalebox{#1}{\fryingpan}}
```

and the calls for getting double size would be

```
\mfryingpan{2}
\mnapgniyrf{2}
```

Comment: Macro `\fryingpan` has already an optional argument for scaling: `\fryingpan[2]`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Unfortunately, using the optional argument adds a space.